# Lockout request timeout exceeded error after executing stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, locking, ssms, execution

Please see below stored proc. Whenever I execute it I am getting Lockout request time out error and already server has been restarted twice to progress with my work. Please let me know how to resolve this:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON

GO


SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

GO


CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_WarehouseAttendance_New]

AS

BEGIN

      -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from

      -- interfering with SELECT statements.

SET NOCOUNT ON




---------delete existing warehouse table------------------------------

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.WarehouseAttendance_New', 'U')  IS NOT NULL

   DROP TABLE dbo.WarehouseAttendance_New; 

--------Create New Table--------------------------------------------------

---Weeks------------------------------------------------------------------

With weeks as 

(select VDC_week_no, VDC_cal_year, min(VDC_day_date) as WeekCommence

from sql10.ng.dbo.Vdaily_calender

where VDC_avail = 'T'

group by VDC_week_no, VDC_cal_year),


---TTWeeks----------------------------------------------------------------

TTWeeks  as


(SELECT VDC_Cal_Year as REMSYear, [VDC_week_no] as WholeYearWeekNo, WeekCommence,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY vdc_cal_year ORDER BY VDC_week_no)  as TermTimeWeekNo FROM weeks)


---Main----------------------------------------------------------------------

SELECT    CASE WHEN STYR_Age_end_Aug < 16 THEN  '1416' WHEN STYR_Age_end_Aug  < 19 THEN '1618' ELSE '19+'  END AgeBand,

REGT_Year, RTRIM(PRPH_ML1) AS PRPH_ML1,  

RTRIM(PRPH_ML2) AS PRPH_ML2,  

ML2.GNCD_Description AS [Curriculum Area], 

RTrim(PRPH_ML2) AS Section,  

q.GNCD_Description AS Section_Name,  LEFT(q.GNCD_Description, 3) AS Dept, 

rtrim(REGT_Provision_Code) as REGT_Provision_Code, rtrim(PRPH_Title) as PRPH_Title,  

REGT_Student_ID, STEN_Student_ID, STEN_Funding_Stream, STYR_Age_end_Aug, REGS_Session_No, 

rtrim(REGH_Class_Register) as REGH_Class_Register, RTRIM(REGH_Register_Title) as REGH_Register_Title, REGH_Day, 

CASE WHEN REGH_Day =  '1' THEN 'Sunday' WHEN REGH_Day =  '2' THEN 'Monday' 

WHEN REGH_Day = '3'  THEN 'Tuesday' WHEN REGH_Day = '4'  THEN 'Wednesday'

WHEN REGH_Day = '5'  THEN 'Thursday' WHEN REGH_Day = '6'  THEN 'Friday' 

WHEN REGH_Day = '7'  THEN 'Saturday' END AS Register_Day, [REGH_Start_Time] ,[REGH_End_Time],

CASE WHEN (REGTrgstudt.REGT_Provision_Code LIKE '27%'  OR

REGT_Provision_Code  LIKE 'MA27%' OR  REGT_Provision_Code LIKE  'FS%') 

THEN 'FunctionalSkill' 

WHEN REGT_Provision_Code LIKE '16%'  THEN 'GCSE' WHEN REGT_Provision_Code LIKE '%/F%'  OR REGT_Provision_Code LIKE  '%/D%' OR

REGT_Provision_Code  LIKE '%/E%' OR

REGT_Provision_Code  LIKE '%/X%' THEN 'Main' ELSE  'Addition' END AS CourseType, 

CASE WHEN isnull(RGAT_Present,'X') IN ('N', 'Y','X') and REGS_Session_Date<GETDATE()

THEN REGS_Duration - isnull(REGD_Mins_Late,0) ELSE 0 END  AS Mins_Poss, 

CASE WHEN isnull(RGAT_Present,'X') = 'Y'  and REGS_Session_Date<GETDATE() THEN 

REGS_Duration  - REGD_Mins_Late ELSE 0  END AS Mins_Att, 

CASE WHEN RGAT_Present = 'Y' and REGS_Session_Date<GETDATE() THEN REGD_Mins_Late ELSE 0 END AS Mins_Late, 

[REGS_Session_Date]  as Session_Date,

TermTimeWeekNo, REGH_ISN, PRPH_ISN, STUD_Surname, 

STUD_Forename_1, REGD_Attendance_Mark,

REGT_start_date, REGT_End_date, WeekCommence,

STFM_LearnFAMCode,

CASE 

WHEN STFM_LearnFAMCode=1 THEN '14-15 year old learner is eligible for free meals'

WHEN STFM_LearnFAMCode=2 THEN '16-19 year old learner is eligible for and in receipt of free meals'

ELSE 'N/A'

END AS FreeMealsIndicator,

CASE 

STFM_LearnFAMCode=36 THEN 'Care to Learn (C2L) (EFA funded only)'

STFM_LearnFAMCode=55 THEN '16-19 Bursary Fund - learner member of a vulnerable group (EFA funded only)'     

WHEN STFM_LearnFAMCode=56 THEN '16-19 Bursary Fund - learner awarded discretionary bursary (EFA funded only)'      

WHEN STFM_LearnFAMCode=57 THEN 'Residential support (EFA funded only)'

WHEN STFM_LearnFAMCode=58 THEN '19+ Hardship (Skills Funding Agency funded learners only)'      

WHEN STFM_LearnFAMCode=59 THEN '20+ Childcare (Skills Funding Agency funded learners only)'      

WHEN STFM_LearnFAMCode=60 THEN 'Residential Access Fund (Skills Funding Agency funded learners only)'   

WHEN STFM_LearnFAMCode IN (61, 62, 63, 64, 65) THEN 'Unassigned'  

ELSE 'N/A'

END AS Bursary,  CASE WHEN STUD_Gender='M' THEN 'Male'

WHEN STUD_Gender='F' THEN 'Female'

END AS Gender,  

CASE 

WHEN STUD_Ethnicity= 31 THEN 'White - English / Welsh / Scottish / Northern Irish / British'

WHEN  STUD_Ethnicity= 32 THEN 'White - Irish'

WHEN  STUD_Ethnicity= 33 THEN 'White - Gypsy or Irish Traveller'

WHEN  STUD_Ethnicity= 34 THEN 'White - Any Other White background'

WHEN  STUD_Ethnicity= 35 THEN 'Mixed / Multiple Ethnic group - White and Black Caribbean'

WHEN  STUD_Ethnicity= 36 THEN 'Mixed / Multiple Ethnic group - White and Black African'

WHEN  STUD_Ethnicity= 37 THEN 'Mixed / Multiple Ethnic group - White and Asian'

WHEN  STUD_Ethnicity= 38 THEN 'Mixed / Multiple Ethnic group - Any Other Mixed / multiple ethnic background'

WHEN  STUD_Ethnicity= 39 THEN 'Asian / Asian British - Indian'

WHEN  STUD_Ethnicity= 40 THEN 'Asian/ Asian British - Pakistani'

WHEN  STUD_Ethnicity= 41 THEN 'Asian / Asian British - Bangladeshi'

WHEN  STUD_Ethnicity= 42 THEN 'Asian / Asian British - Chinese'

WHEN  STUD_Ethnicity= 43 THEN 'Asian / Asian British - Any other Asian background'

WHEN  STUD_Ethnicity= 44 THEN 'Black / African / Caribbean / Black British - African'

WHEN  STUD_Ethnicity= 45 THEN 'Black / African / Caribbean / Black British - Caribbean'

WHEN  STUD_Ethnicity= 46 THEN 'Black / African / Caribbean / Black British - Any other Black / African / Caribbean background'

WHEN  STUD_Ethnicity= 47 THEN 'Other ethnic group - Arab'

WHEN  STUD_Ethnicity= 98 THEN 'Any Other'

WHEN  STUD_Ethnicity= 99 THEN 'Not provided'

END AS Ethnicity,

CASE 

WHEN g.GNUC_Flag_1 = 1 THEN  'Yes'

WHEN g.GNUC_Flag_1 = 0 THEN  'No'

END AS [Looked After Child],

CASE 

WHEN SUB1.GNUC_Type = 'STYR'  THEN 'Yes'

WHEN SUB1.GNUC_Type != 'STYR'  THEN 'No'

END AS ALS

INTO WarehouseAttendance_New                    

FROM        

sql10.ng.dbo.REGTrgstudt 

INNER JOIN

sql10.ng.dbo.REGSrgsessn ON REGT_REGH_ISN = REGS_REGH_ISN  

inner join sql10.ng.dbo.Vdaily_calender

ON REGS_Session_Date=VDC_day_date      

INNER JOIN TTWeeks on REGT_year=TTWeeks.REMSYear

and VDC_week_no=WholeYearWeekNo and VDC_cal_year=REMSYear

INNER JOIN

sql10.ng.dbo.REGHrghdr ON REGH_ISN = REGT_REGH_ISN 

INNER JOIN

sql10.ng.dbo.PRPHProvisionHeader ON REGT_Provision_Code = PRPH_Code 

INNER JOIN

sql10.ng.dbo.GNCDgncodes AS ML2 ON ML2.GNCD_General_Code = PRPH_ML2 AND ML2.GNCD_Code_Type = 'M2' 

INNER JOIN

sql10.ng.dbo.STEN ON STEN_Student_ID = REGTrgstudt.REGT_Student_ID AND STEN_Provision_Code  = REGTrgstudt.REGT_Provision_Code  AND

STEN_Provision_Instance = REGT_Provision_Instance 

LEFT OUTER JOIN  sql10.ng.dbo.STFMLearnerFAM ON STFM_Year = STEN_Year AND STFM_Student_ID = STEN_Student_ID 

INNER JOIN

sql10.ng.dbo.STYRstudentYR ON STYR_Student_ID = REGT_Student_ID AND STYR_Year = REGT_Year   

INNER JOIN (SELECT GNUC_Type, GNUC_Year, GNUC_Entity_ISN FROM sql10.ng.dbo.GNUCustom 

WHERE  (GNUC_Year IN ('2013', '2014',  '2015'))) AS SUB1 ON REGT_Year = SUB1.GNUC_Year 

--AND STYR_ISN = SUB1.GNUC_Entity_ISN

INNER JOIN

(SELECT     ACYR_College_Year

FROM          sql10.ng.dbo.ACYR

WHERE      (ACYR_College_Year in (2015, 2014, 2013, 2012))) AS SUB ON REGT_Year = SUB.ACYR_College_Year

INNER JOIN sql10.ng.dbo.STUDStudent on STYR_Student_ID=STUD_Student_ID

JOIN sql10.ng.dbo.GNUCustom g ON STUD_ISN = g.GNUC_Entity_ISN AND g.GNUC_Type  = 'STUD'       

INNER JOIN sql10.ng.dbo.REGDropin ON REGT_REGH_ISN = REGD_REGH_ISN AND REGT_Student_ID = REGD_Student_ID 

AND 

REGD_Session_No  = REGS_Session_No

INNER JOIN

sql10.ng.dbo.RGATAttendance ON REGD_Attendance_Mark  = RGAT_Attendance_Code 

INNER JOIN

sql10.ng.dbo.PRPIProvisionInstance AS pit ON pit.PRPI_Code 
= REGT_Provision_Code 
and pit.prpi_instance = REGT_Provision_Instance

INNER JOIN

(SELECT     GNCD_General_Code, GNCD_Description

FROM          sql10.ng.dbo.GNCDgncodes

WHERE      (GNCD_Code_Type = 'M2')) AS q ON q.GNCD_General_Code =  RTrim(PRPH_ML2) 

END 

GO
```

[image: Lock error]

Execution Plan below:

[image: Execution Plan]

Client Statistics:

[image: Client_Stats]

Comment: you are joining linked tables with local tables, so behind the scenes, SQL is more than likely bringing all data from remote tables local to temdb so it can join. look at an execution plan to confirm if this is correct. you need to rethink this solution to avoid joining cross-server.

Comment: @Jeremy - Please take a look at above screenshots. Thanks!